# How to use output of command multiple time in single line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have this command `git init lerna-repo && cd lerna-repo`  where I am repeating `learna-repo`. I want to know how can I make it minimal so I only have to write `learna-repo` once.

I tried something and found that I use something like `repo="larna-repo" && git init $repo && cd $repo` but this keeps variable in the shell (After that if I run `echo $repo` variable is still there).

Can I do something like pipe `|` for passing it temporarily like `echo "Hello World!" | grep "Hello"` but want to use the output multiple times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line, you can use <kbd>Alt-.</kbd> to repeat the last argument from the previous command:

```
git init lerna-repo
cd Alt-.
```

Or, you can use history expansion:

```
git init lerna-repo
cd !:2  # Repeats the second argument
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash [History Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction), you would type

```bsh
git init lerna-repo && cd !#:2
```

where:

- `!#` is the current command line, and
- `:2` is the third word.

But if this is something you do a lot, write a function:

```bsh
gicd() { 
    git init "$1" && cd "$1"
}

gicd lerna-repo
```